# Azure alert not working

Tags: azure, alerts

Does anyone know why my Azure alert isn't working? I've created an alert using **response time** as the metric and **5 seconds** as the threshold, 15 minutes as the evaluation window.

As you can see in the linked image, the response time has been above 30 seconds for most of the previous 2 hours but there are no alerts.

[image: Azure Console]

Answer (score 2):

Because that's below for less than 15 minutes (the evaluation window).